# Do Balancer swaps only update the state of the Vault?

Tags: transactions, defi, swaps, amm, balancer

I'm trying to understand the Balancer v2 architecture.

When a swap occurs in a given pool_id, does this *only result in updating the state of the Vault*, and pool contracts themselves are just constant math logic, never having any state updates after they're deployed?

Suppose I make a swap and store my input and output balances inside the Vault, and flag that I want outputs to go into my Vault balance. Will I pay the gas for one transaction?

And if I use balances outside the Vault for input and wish to transfer proceeds of the swap to an address outside the Vault, will the whole swap in this case incur gas fees for **3** transactions - the transfer into the vault for input, the transaction itself, and the transfer of out_asset to my target address?